# Vue-i18n setLocale

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

let's say the code is:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(lang, i) in $i18n.availableLocales" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang">
    <a href="#" @click="setLocale('what shall I write in here?')">
      <span> {{ lang.toUpperCase() }} </span>
    </a>
  </li>
 
</ul>
```

And so the question is `('what shall I write in here?')`

The setLocale function:

```
setLocale(locale) {
      this.$i18n.locale = locale;
      this.$router.push({
        params: { lang: locale },
      });
    },
```

I tried to use `${$i18n.availableLocales}` but it changes locale to `IT, FR, EN` (altogether, which is all available locales, what totally makes sense).

I just can't figure it out on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: `setLocale(lang)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to set it to the `lang` like this:

```
@click="setLocale(lang)
```

Then your `setLocale` function will be passed in the right locale for the users selection.